# My Visual Studio Code can't catch simple obvious errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, omnisharp

I am very new to Visual Studio Code and C#, and struggling that VS can't even catch a simple errors such as typos or random stuff. I already downloaded many recommended extensions, and I think I am missing something very important.
Looking forward to your helps. Many thanks in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLTYk.png)
[OmniSharp Server is not running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZygN.png)

Comment: Have you created a project in your code directory?  The prompt in the left pane to create a `launch.json` suggests you're just editing standalone files.  Otherwise, what happens when you try to build the code?

Comment: I am opening Visual Studio Code with a new Script from Unity. The console in Unity shows the coding errors when I compile, but I was expecting that VS Code could catch simple typos.

Comment: Yes, that `Problems` tab should display errors and warnings as you type and after you compile.  I would try clicking that `Generate C# Assets for Build and Debug` button on the left.  Just to confirm, Microsoft's C# extension (`ms-dotnettools.csharp`) was among those you installed?

Comment: Yes, I have C# extension. I got an "Unable to generate assets to build and debug. OmniSharp server is not running." message, so I followed those steps, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62558818/unable-to-generate-assets-to-build-and-debug-omnisharp-server-is-not-running
but was not working for me. :(

Comment: I installed old version and now it works! thank you so much for your comments